# using ModelView in View in MVVM + WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a model called `Entity` which is created by EF database first :

```
public partial class Entity
    {
        public Entity()
        {
            this.Properties = new HashSet<Property>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }
```

I want this model Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for notifying when X and Y are changing so I created another model like `CEntity`

```
public class CEntity : Entity, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _x;
        private int _y;

        public CEntity()
        {
        }

        public CEntity(long id, string name, int x, int y)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            _x = x;
            _y = y;
        }

        public int X
        {
            get => _x;
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
        public int Y
        {
            get => _y;
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This is `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="DomainModelEditor.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example.UI"
        xmlns:example="clr-namespace:Example"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Example.Models"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Example.UI.ViewModels"
        Title="Modeler" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="26">
                <Label Content="Domain Model Editor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Width="80" Content="Add Entity" Margin="0,3,0,3" Click="AddEntity_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="EditorCanvas" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entities}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=(models:CEntity.X)}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=(models:CEntity.Y)}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:CEntity}">
                    <Thumb HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" DragDelta="Thumb_OnDragDelta" MouseDoubleClick="Thumb_MouseDoubleClick">
                        <Thumb.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle Width="80" Height="50" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Stroke="Black" Fill="LightBlue"/>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Thumb.Template>
                    </Thumb>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have `Entities` in my viewmodel as below:

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository _entityRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MainViewModel(IEntityRepository entityRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _entityRepository = entityRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        Entity = new CEntity();
        Entities = new ObservableCollection<CEntity>();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var entities = _entityRepository.GetAll().Select(entity => new CEntity()
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Name = entity.Name,
            X = entity.X,
            Y = entity.Y
        });

        Entities.Clear();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Entities.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CEntity> Entities { get; set; }

    public void Add(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        var entity = new Entity()
        {
            Name = name,
            X = x,
            Y = y
        };
        _entityRepository.Add(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

Based on `MVVM` we have to use viewmodel instead of model in view, my problem is this part in view:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=(models:CEntity.X)}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=(models:CEntity.Y)}" />
                </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

When I use Model `CEntity` here it works fine but I don't know what should I put as part of viewmodel instead of CEntity.

Comment: Are `models:CEntity.X` and `models:CEntity.Y` static or instance fields? In snippet they are declared as instance properties. Actially, your `CEntity` looks as viewmodel, not the model

Comment: *Based on MVVM we have to use viewmodel instead of model in view, my problem is this part in view* - you are totally wrong about what is model in MVVM context. The View should only know the ViewModel and the ViewModel should only know the Model. The View can ask the ViewModel for **data** and that data can be contained in an instance of a class that does not have to be a ViewModel but can be a simple POCO class which may also implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: But: *CEntity* should **not** be inherited from *Entity* because that will violate SRP. Use AutoMapper and independent classes (one for storing data, one for presenting) and use AutoMapper to map between them.

Answer (score 0):

`CEntity` should not inherit from `Entity` as it then hides the `X` and `Y` properties.

You'd better use composition and wrap `Entity`:

```
public class CEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Entity _entity;

    public CEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get => _entity.X;
        set
        {
            _entity.X = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get => _entity.Y;
        set
        {
            _entity.Y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can then bind directly to the `X` and `Y` properties as usual:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
```